# No effective root

Tags: command-line, login, root

I wanted to login as a user, but when I typed in `login usr` (`usr` is just a placeholder for the user name) the system returned:

```
login: Cannot possibly work without effective root.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the `login` command succeed by running it as `root` (as the error message says).

You can run `login username` as root by using `sudo`:

```
sudo login username
```

Unless you've very recently run a command with `sudo` in the shell *you're already in*, you'll first be prompted to enter *your* password as an administrator who is able to run commands as `root` with `sudo`.

Then the `login` command will run, it will prompt for **`username`**'s password, and if the password is successfully entered, you'll get a login as **`username`**.

However, you probably do not need a *real* login as **`username`**:

- To start a login shell as **`username`**, run:

  ```
  sudo -i -u username
  ```

  This requires no authentication except for the initial `sudo` authentication (when you enter *your* password, *not* **`username`**'s password). Only administrators can do this.
- To start a login shell as **`username`**, such that you are prompted for **`username`**'s password (and *not* prompted for your own password), run:

  ```
  su - username
  ```

  Any user (except Guest) can do this, provided that they know **`username`**'s password.

For more information about running commands as `root`, see [the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).