# After login as a particular user, how do I login as another user?

Tags: login, login-screen, putty, remote-login

Such a basic thing I can't find anywhere in google.

I just need to re login as another user, without having to annoyingly logout. Logout closes my putty terminal, and I have to relaunch and reconnect again

Comment: Do these help? - https://askubuntu.com/questions/492312/terminal-command-login-fails-with-error-message - https://askubuntu.com/questions/276172/no-effective-root

Comment: `su` or substitute user.

Comment: su!!! omg thank you!